# How to use Angular directive inside Kendo Grid Column

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

This is relatively simple, or so I would have thought.

I have a custom Angular directive - I can add it to the DOM with

```
<custom-directive ng-model="someAngularScopeObject"></custom-directive>
```

My question, is how can I use this into Kendo Grid column template.

My grid is defined using DOM angular attributes, and the kendo grid k-options are specified in the angular scope.

For column template, how can I bind the row's column dataItem to my custom directives ng-model?

Basically, in the grid's k-options:

```
columns: [
        { field: "name", title: "Name" },
        { field: "description", title: "Description" },
        { field: "managerName", title: "Manager",
            template: function (dataItem) {
                //what I care about is dataItem.prop1
                return ("<custom-directive ng-model='???????????'>
                         </custom-directive>");     
        }
    }]
```

The grid and the grid's data source are on the Angular's controller's scope

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to edit the grid column data inside the directive?

Comment: For now, I was just trying to do the R-O template, but eventually, I would also bind a different directive in the editor template. But the directive has 2 way binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a R-O template you can try it like this:

```
columns: [
    { field: "name", title: "Name" },
    { field: "description", title: "Description" },
    { field: "managerName", title: "Manager",
        template: function (dataItem) {
            //what I care about is dataItem.prop1
            var scope = angular.element("idofelement_with_your_scope").scope();
            scope.someAngularScopeObject = dataItem.prop1;
            return ("<custom-directive ng-model='someAngularScopeObject'>
                     </custom-directive>");     
    }
}]
```

I haven't tested it but is should do the job. The idea is that in the `template` function you have a value and in the directive you need an property/object to bind to.